# Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression, @ts-morph/common/dist/typescript.js npx create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, ts-morph

I was trying to import,

```
import { createProject, ts } from "@ts-morph/bootstrap";
```

But every time built failed, due to complied with warnings,

Compiled with warnings.

```
./node_modules/@ts-morph/common/dist/typescript.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

./node_modules/@ts-morph/common/dist/typescript.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

./node_modules/@ts-morph/common/dist/typescript.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'perf_hooks' in '\node_modules\@ts-morph\common\dist'
```

I am using react, by create-react-app, anyone knows how to solve it? Also, I have tried with @carco to extends the webpack config to add noParse Module, but it's not working.

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        module:{
            noParse: [/\/typescript\.js/]
        }
    },
  }
```

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39436#issuecomment-739546225 -- I think that needs to be resolved.

Comment: The issue you linked is marked as resolved but OP's problem persists. The 'workaround' webpack config mentioned in the Github issue gets rid of the errors, but also prevents the page to render.